# How can I create a link for patrons to pay for an event using PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I'm running a concert and I want to be able to have people buy will-call tickets via PayPal.  I am familiar with creating a 'buy it now' button, and have created some effectively in the past.

However, I'd like to be able to just create a non-form based URL
that will direct people to a payment page, so I can post it on sites where
I can't create an HTML form (forums, social network sites, etc.)

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to host a page elsewhere where you can render the form required for a Buy It Now button (or any other of the PayPal payment methods). I don't know of a way to do it from a single URL.

Comment: Totally reasonable suggestion.  I'm already doing that, and it may be the best/only answer.  I just wanted to minimize the number of re-directions that a user had to go through, if possible.